# Deep Clone Entity Without Serialization

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework, serialization

I need to deep clone an Entity (To use an existing Entity as pattern for a new one). I found several approaches, but all include Serialization. Since our Entities derive from ObservableObject of the MVVM Toolkit that is not Serializeable we can't use those approaches.

What would be the best way to do so?

We are usinng .net 4.5 and EF5 and WPF.

Comment: Why you cannot serialize it exactly? With enough reflection, everything is serializable.

Comment: Side note: please avoid adding signatures to your question as you already have one in user name [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#signatures).

Comment: It is? Can you give me an example. I haven't used Serialization a lot...

Comment: It is not a good idea to have your data objects double as business objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. One method is to simply write custom code that will perform the clone for you. Given an object, new an instance, and then for each property write some code that will give you a deep copy of that property, perhaps recursively chaining down your object graph for complex properties.
2. Another option is create a model that stores your important data, serialize that, and then deserialize and restore data from that temporary serializable model into a new entity object.

Answer (score 0):

You can use some libraries for deep cloning. It is slower than manual implementation (and with manual implementation you can optimize your task by copying only required properties), but in general, this libraries are useful for *general* copying.

My favorite is [DeepCloner](https://www.nuget.org/packages/DeepCloner/), also, you can see at [CloneExtensions](https://www.nuget.org/packages/CloneExtensions/)